# Bootstrap 3: Reorder stacked columns on mobile screens

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create one of those features pages that Google uses everywhere. On a desktop browser, it would alternate between image and text (on the first row, it's image then text; one the next row it's text then image).

However, on mobile screens - I need to make sure that the image always precedes the text (since it provides context). Here's an illustration:

[image: Desired Desktop vs. Mobile view]

I tried using the `col-md-pull` and `col-md-push` features of Bootstrap to reorder them on mobile screens, but it didn't work.

Here's my code .. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"><img src="..."></div>
        <div class="col-md-8">Feature 1 ...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-4">Feature 2 ...</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-4"><img src="..."></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please refer to this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o8z7Lbnu/2/)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img data-src="holder.js/100px150?bg=F3C40F">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h1>Feature 1</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, debitis, reiciendis, repudiandae, placeat recusandae maxime fugiat explicabo voluptatem omnis commodi molestiae assumenda repellendus. Sequi, id ducimus cumque dolore ipsum beatae?</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8">
        <img data-src="holder.js/100px150?bg=F3C40F">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-4">
        <h1>Feature 2</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, voluptatum, aut, eius, ut sunt quod quia maiores eos deleniti provident delectus dicta facere eum quasi harum esse aspernatur! Quas, cumque.</p>
    </div>     
</div>
```

I think that will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Reorder your HTML within the second `.row` (place the image above feature two):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">Feature 1 ...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-4">Feature 2</div>     
    </div>
</div>
```

Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/5839/

Comment: Not it doesn't give me the desired Desktop view